Unable to run chromium in Python
I would like to run chromium in my python script.
Here is my test code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()

But I am getting selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
If I check in bash chromium location which chromedriver I get the correct location /usr/bin/chromedriver. Where is the problem, please?

@MT1 yes, but no meaningful answer there.

Do you actually want to use that specific ChromeDriver (/usr/bin/chromedriver) for automation? If not, just go with @JeffC's answer. Selenium 4 automatically downloads the required WebDriver versions for you by using Selenium Manager. If you want to your installed ChromeDriver executable, please provide more debugging information. Maybe add log_output=sys.stderr to the Service arguments to see why it exits with status code 1.

@mwopitz You can customize Selenium Manager as well to use certain versions and a lot of other options. My answer just shows the basics of getting a script started.

My assumption is that your Service-related code and/or path is not correct. You no longer need all of that to get Selenium working. The minimal code below should work just fine.
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()

